# How to hide any item in select > option dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Today, I have two question with my problem.

**First question:**

I was using the loop to `foreach` an array.

I only get two option with having values.

Like this:

```
<select>
   <option disable>     Angust      </option>
   <option disable>     October     </option>
   <option values="20"> Noel        </option>
   <option disable>     November    </option>
   <option disable>     December    </option>
   <option values="34"> Happy new year </option>
</select>
```

And have any method to hidden all option with an attribute is `disable`, exception option have attribute `values`.

**Second question:**

So, when I tried to loop table `special_month` table, I want to get only `<option>` have `values`.

And when to selected a `<option>`, I also get values and get the name of this item selected using method `POST`.

Ex:

I selected:

`<option values="34"> Happy new year </option>`.

So, I want get `id` with `values = 34` and get `name` with `values = Happy new year`.

Comment: it should be value and not values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It should be `disabled` and not `disable` (missing the `d` in the end)
2. It should be `value` and not `values` (the `s` in the end shouldn't be there)
3. If you want you can use `css` to hide the disabled options:

```css
#s2 option[disabled] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="s1">
   <option disabled="disabled">     Angust      </option>
   <option disabled="disabled">     October     </option>
   <option value="20"> Noel        </option>
   <option disabled="disabled">     November    </option>
   <option disabled="disabled">     December    </option>
   <option value="34"> Happy new year </option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select id="s2">
   <option disabled="disabled">     Angust      </option>
   <option disabled="disabled">     October     </option>
   <option value="20"> Noel        </option>
   <option disabled="disabled">     November    </option>
   <option disabled="disabled">     December    </option>
   <option value="34"> Happy new year </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much.